# Show that the projection vector of $\vec b$ on $\vec a$, $a \ne 0$ is $\bigg( \frac{\vec a .\vec b}{|\vec a|^2}\bigg)\vec a$.

Tags: vectors

Show that the projection vector of $\vec b$ on $\vec a$, $a \ne 0$ is $\bigg( \frac{\vec a .\vec b}{|\vec a|^2}\bigg)\vec a$.

My attempt: As per formula, the projection of $\vec b$ on $\vec a$ is $\frac{\vec b \cdot \vec a}{|\vec a|}$. However, the solution demands multiplying it with $\frac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}$. I am not sure I understand why would that happen. Please help.

Comment: Well, $\vec a.\vec b/|\vec a|$ is the coordinate of $\vec b$ in direction $\vec a$, i.e., a number and not a vector itself.

Comment: Please see the projection paragraph in https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/dotprod/dotprod.html

Comment: And this coordinate must be in the direction of $\overrightarrow{a}$. In fact the projection vector will be $\dfrac{\overrightarrow{a}.\overrightarrow{b}}{\left| \overrightarrow{a} \right|}$ times the unit vector along $\overrightarrow{a}$ which gives the required result

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I guess you made the point clear to me, thank you.

Comment: @TRUSKI thanks for sharing the resource. It helped.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Yes, I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show this vector, when subtracted from $\vec{b}$, gives something orthogonal to $\vec{a}$. Indeed $$(\vec{b}-\lambda\vec{a})\cdot\vec{a}=\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}-\lambda\|\vec{a}|^2,$$ which is $0$ for $\lambda=\frac{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}{|\vec{a}|^2}$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what is orthogonal, my level of mathematics is not nearly as advanced as the content of your answer. I am a high school student.

Comment: @AakhiChatterjee Vectors $\vec{u},\,\vec{v}$ are orthogonal or perpendicular if $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a property of the dot product that:

$$\vec a \cdot \vec b=|\vec a||\vec b|\cos \theta$$

Thus, if $\vec u$ is a unit vector:

$$\vec u \cdot \vec b=|\vec u||\vec b|\cos \theta=|\vec b|\cos \theta$$

is the **scalar projection** of $\vec b$ on $\vec u$ and

$$(\vec u \cdot \vec b)\vec u$$

is the **vector projection** of $\vec b$ on $\vec u$.

Now in your case the unitary vector for $\vec a$ is

$$\vec u= \frac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}$$

Thus the vector projection of $\vec b$ on $\vec a$ is given by

> $$\left(\frac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}\cdot \vec b\right)\frac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}=\left(\frac{\vec a}{|\vec a|^2}\cdot \vec b\right)\vec a$$